# Put a shape at the start and end of a line in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, line, stroke

I'm using System.Windows.Shapes.Line in my application to draw a line on a canvas. I want to put a shape e.g. a cross ('x') at the start and end of the line? Is there any way to do this by setting a property. I can add a 'x' on the canvas based on the coordinates but I was hoping if we can do this using some Line property directly.
Currently I'm able to draw this = ---------------
[dashed line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEPwy.png) using the properties as in the snippet under:-

```
var DistanceLine = new Line();
DistanceLine.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(LineColor);
DistanceLine.StrokeDashArray = new DoubleCollection() {0, 4};
DistanceLine.StrokeDashCap = PenLineCap.Round;
DistanceLine.StrokeEndLineCap = PenLineCap.Round;
DistanceLine.StrokeLineJoin = PenLineJoin.Round;
DistanceLine.StrokeStartLineCap = PenLineCap.Round;
DistanceLine.StrokeThickness = 3;
```

I want something like this = x------------------x
[dashed line with 'x' marks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmaWz.png)

How can I make a custom shape at the end of the lines?

Comment: There is the StrokeStartLineCap and StrokeEndLineCap properties: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754071(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @mm8  I'm already using the StrokeStartLineCap and StrokeEndLineCap (as you can see in the edited question).

Comment: What do you mean by "the 4 enumerations of PenLineCap do not seem to serve the purpose"? Check the example in the documentation.

Comment: @mm8 What I mean is that the 4 enumerations of PenLineCap have shapes which are based on the stroke thickness.
I'm unable to figure out putting a custom shape at the ends of the line (as depicted in the pictures attached). Unfortunately, couldn't find a similar question on so.

Comment: Of course they "serve a purpose" as explained in the documentation. Try to increase the thickness and get rid of the dash array and you will clearly see a difference between flat and round caps.

Comment: @mm8 Really appreciate your prompt responses. I understand  the difference between round and flat caps. As I said and in attached pictures, I want to put a custom shape without changing thickness of the line. That's where it got trickier for me.

Comment: Custom line caps are trickier but you could refer to the following blog post: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mrochon/2011/01/09/custom-line-caps-in-wpf/.

Comment: Unfortunately WPF doesn't have anything like the `marker-end` in SVG so you'll have to make your own, like the example mm8 linked.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer 
Thanks for your comments. I now implemented my own line cap as needed. :)

Comment: @mm8 Please look this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47871928/wpf-datagrid-gridlines-not-visible-when-saved-as-pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments suggested and encouraged me to write my own shape to put at the line caps. This may not be the best approach but works for me well. The class returns an object as a Grid which I can add to my canvas when I draw a line. This is how I've done it:-

```
public class CrossHair : Grid
    {
        public string LineName { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Draws the crosshair at the given point
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="x"></param>
        /// <param name="y"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        static public CrossHair DrawCrossHair(double x, double y)
        {
            var crosshair = new CrossHair(); // to contain the cross hair
            var line1 = new Line();
            var line2 = new Line();
            var line3 = new Line();
            var line4 = new Line();
            line1.Stroke = line2.Stroke = line3.Stroke = line4.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
            line1.StrokeThickness = line2.StrokeThickness = line3.StrokeThickness = line4.StrokeThickness = 2;

            line1.X1 = x - 5;
            line1.Y1 = y;
            line1.X2 = x - 2;
            line1.Y2 = y;

            line2.X1 = x;
            line2.Y1 = y + 5;
            line2.X2 = x;
            line2.Y2 = y + 2;

            line3.X1 = x + 2;
            line3.Y1 = y;
            line3.X2 = x + 5;
            line3.Y2 = y;

            line4.X1 = x;
            line4.Y1 = y - 2;
            line4.X2 = x;
            line4.Y2 = y - 5;

            crosshair.Children.Add(line1);
            crosshair.Children.Add(line2);
            crosshair.Children.Add(line3);
            crosshair.Children.Add(line4);

            return crosshair;
        }
    }
```